# Group Artists in Deezer by tags

Tags: deezer

Does Deezer have any way to group list of artist by tags, category, custom user comment or other way?

I have long list of Artist and want to group (or order) them by my own custom parameters (for example, by style, by music type, etc). I know that I can create custom playlists, but in playlist I can add only single songs, not the whole artist.

Is there any solution for this task - group/filter artist list by custom user tags?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "genre" endpoint available here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/genre#connections. You can retrieve the artists by genre, or podcasts and radios if you want.

Comment: This question is about HTML frontend interface, not for API calls. Users must have any way for filter his list of Artists / Albums / Tracks by tags (global and local) and genre, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML frontend interface"? Our JS SDK?

Comment: I mean http://www.deezer.com/en/ website - me (and, I think, many other users) want to organize my collection by local and global tags in your official site, not in external tools. Or maybe you can do this via external app in http://www.deezer.com/appstudio ?

Also this feature will be welcome in Mobile apps (Android, iOS).

Comment: Sorry, so it is not a technical issue on our SDKs, but a feature request that you are mentioning. Sorry, but there is no possibility to do that for now on our website/application